# Clear/unset a system property maven.compiler.release so that is is no longer present

Tags: java, maven, maven-compiler-plugin, system-properties

I have a project with complicated build setup (parent POM's with parent POM's) and so it happens that my compiler plugin executes with `maven.compiler.release=8`.

This prevents me from setting source/target to Java 11 and I can't set release to 11 since I need to specify some `--add-exports`.

Is there a way to remove a system property in a profile so that it will not appear and my source/target switches would work? The best I could think of is setting `maven.compiler.release` to empty value but it won't work with compiler plugin.

How do I clear the system property in a profile? Alternatively, is there a way to trace who actually set it in the first place?

Comment: Using `maven.compiler.release` with JDK 8 will fail because the `--release` option is supported starting with JDK9+... For JDK11 you can simply set it to `<maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>`.. If you set release you don't need source/target anymore..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar problem.  Here is how to delete `release` property from parent POM and use `--add-exports`.

Use the `combine.self="override"` attribute like this

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <release combine.self="override"/>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>--add-exports</arg>
                    <arg>jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-NNAMED</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
                ...
```

*et, voila!*